# Can Tkiner.after schedule a function after fraction of a ms?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a naive question regarding tkinter after method.

The [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) says the time is in milliseconds - can I schedule something in fraction of a millisecond? say 0.5ms?

Comment: [Documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/after.htm) says ms must be an integer.

Comment: Also the error, which raised when you trying to do such things, is self explanatory. `_tkinter.TclError: bad argument "0.5": must be cancel, idle, info, or an integer`

Comment: Don't use `tk.after`, call the function directly!

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot schedule something less than 1ms in tkinter.